# How to post image and text on facebook wall without using open graph API

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook

I have developed a sample project where i am displaying Text and an Image and i am able to post it on facebook wall . I have shown the code and the image of it below .This appears like how we add a photo into our wall with status message

```
- (IBAction)postStatusUpdateClick:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIImage *image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-72@2x.png"];


    NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [params setObject:@"Test with Image" forKey:@"message"];
    [params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:@"picture"];
    shareOnFacebook.enabled = NO; //for not allowing multiple hits

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             //showing an alert for failure
             [self showAlert:@"Facebook unable to share photo " result:result error:error];
         }
         else
         {
             //showing an alert for success
             [self showAlert:@"Facebook share photo successful" result:result error:error];
         }
         shareOnFacebook.enabled = YES;
     }];
}


// UIAlertView helper for post buttons
- (void)showAlert:(NSString *)message
           result:(id)result
            error:(NSError *)error {

    NSString *alertMsg;
    NSString *alertTitle;
    if (error) {
        alertTitle = @"Error";
        if (error.fberrorShouldNotifyUser ||
            error.fberrorCategory == FBErrorCategoryPermissions ||
            error.fberrorCategory == FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession) {
            alertMsg = error.fberrorUserMessage;
        } else {
            alertMsg = @"Operation failed due to a connection problem, retry later.";
        }
    } else {
        NSDictionary *resultDict = (NSDictionary *)result;
        alertMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Successfully posted '%@'.\nPost ID: %@",
                    message, [resultDict valueForKey:@"id"]];
        alertTitle = @"Success";
    }

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle
                                                        message:alertMsg
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

[image]

*****Now i want to display in proper format like in the one in scrumptious example from facebook.**
[image]

**I want to do it without open graph api . Can anyone help me in this**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post Image with Text on FB Wall without using Open Graph API >> http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/how-to-upload-photo-and-update-status.html

**Updated Answer**

Post Image and Text on facebook using FB iOS SDK 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/

Cheers,
Ravi

Comment: i have already done that way .. now i want to do like i have shown in image 2 in my question

Comment: Not sure if you can do those small things without Open Graph API.

Comment: do u know how to do it using open graph API?

Comment: weren't you using Open Graph before ?

Comment: Nope ..or am i using Open Graph ?? ..i dont know how to put it content like it is shown in 2nd image in my question.

Comment: `Sorry, the link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed.` @RaviTrivedi

Comment: Post on Facebook wall programmatically ios , is it feasible?

Answer (score 1):

Just open this url in mobile safari.It will show share dialog

```
    "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?fbapp_id=yorfbappId&name=Test&description=test&redirect_uri=fbyourfbappid%3A%2F%2Fauthorize&sdk=ios"
```